# Could a moderator reset this user's account?

Tags: support

Recently, I flagged one of [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/114781/bob) user's answers as offensive. Now, I just noticed his website was something vulgar. Could a moderator reset his account/reset his website?

Comment: In the future, just raise a flag for moderator intervention.

Comment: How to raise on an account?

Comment: Bah all his posts are deleted. Uh... Good question

Comment: there's this meta post about the same type of issue, I believe same applies here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285204/flag-user-profile

Comment: "Alternatively, you can email `team@stackoverflow.com` and explain your concern." by @LeakyCode from meta.stackexchange. This bit of answer is from 2009 though, so might be outdated...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've taken care of the issue, and just removed the information.

Comment: Not just the information, the whole account is gone!

Comment: @Mathias711 - Mods have only one level of power... **kill** :P